# Rename the client computer from Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC)

Tags: active-directory

I am new to Active Directory concepts. I am practicing with AD Objects. In AD, I can change the user object names but I cannot able to rename the computer object name. It can be done via netdom command in powershell but unable to rename via ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers). Is there anyone have the idea about how to rename the computer from ADUC? If it is not possible, please tell the reason for unable to rename through ADUC.

Thanks,
Sathishkumar

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rename computers from  Active Directory Users and Computers.

Use the PowerShell cmdlet `Rename-Computer` instead.

```
Rename-Computer
      [-ComputerName <String>]
      [-PassThru]
      [-DomainCredential <PSCredential>]
      [-LocalCredential <PSCredential>]
      [-NewName] <String>
      [-Force]
      [-Restart]
      [-WsmanAuthentication <String>]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

##### Example:

`Rename-Computer -ComputerName "COMP01" -NewName "WORKSTATION01"`

You could rename the computer from `ADSIEdit` but I strongly advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

Over remote powershell.  You'll always need -domaincredential, even if it's the same as the logged in account.  Make sure no one is logged in before restarting.  I've tried restarting with restart-computer instead, but sometimes there's an error.  Or you can run rename-computer inside invoke-command.

```
invoke-command comp001 { quser } 
$c = get-credential dom\admin
rename-computer -computername comp001 -newname comp002 -Protocol wsman -domaincredential $c -restart

# get camel case
get-computer COMP002 | rename-adobject -newname Comp002
```